# PySpark - how to set up environment variables (not Spark config)?

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

On production cluster I am running Spark via [Spark Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator), which allows me to set environment variables for driver and executors, so I can access them like in my PySpark script:

```
db_table = os.getenv("DB_TABLE")
```

Now I want to do the same locally for testing. I am using [Spark Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark/) in local mode with 1 master and 1 worker in Docker Compose. Tests are running in a separate Docker container in the same Docker network.

How can I do this? I tried:

1. Adding `'--conf "spark.executorEnv.DB_TABLE=table_name"` to `spark-submit`. This is not detected in script.
2. Adding `'--conf "spark.driver.DB_TABLE=table_name"` to `spark-submit`. This is not set as environment variable, but accessible in Spark Context as `spark.conf.get("spark.driver.DB_TABLE")`. This does not work for two reasons:

- I would need to modify script to handle local and production environments separately, which would results in messier and longer code
- I cannot set any Spark options for Spark Context, which I set with `.config("spark.jars", ADDITIONAL_JARS)`, so I need ADDITIONAL_JARS env var

3. Setting env vars in running Spark Docker container from running tests Docker container with `os.system(f'docker exec -i docker-spark-master-1 /bin/bash -c "export DB_TABLE=table_name"')`. This does not work, since I do not have Docker installed inside tests Docker container, and this is an ugly hack anyway.

So how can I set environment variables for PySpark so that they are available as regular environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Does [the documented way](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark#configuration) not work?

> If you want to add a new environment variable:
>
> For `docker-compose` add the variable name and value under the application section in the `docker-compose.yml` file present in this repository:
>
> ```yaml
> spark:
>   ...
>   environment:
>     - DB_TABLE=table_name
>   ...
> ```
>
> For manual execution add a `-e` option with each variable and value:
>
> ```bash
> docker run -d --name spark \
>   --network=spark_network \
>   -e DB_TABLE=table_name \
>   bitnami/spark
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. My setup is as follows: I setup my Docker Compose (database, Elasticsearch, Spark master and worker), wait 15 seconds for Elasticsearch to start in the container, then insert events, and only then start testing container. Running Docker commands in Docker is generally bad idea, so I want to avoid starting Spark in testing container. But every test requires different env vars for Spark, so I hope I can set them up dynamically somehow.